# ssh is using the default key even when I specify a custom key with passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh

I generated default public and private keys on CentOS 8 machine. Copied the public key to another linux VM and ssh connection was sucessful. Then I created a custom pair in a different location than `~/.ssh` and used `ssh -i <privatekey> <ip-address>`. It did not ask me for the passphrase which I setup with the custom keys. I am pretty sure it used the default keys from `~/.ssh` folder. I tested this out by deleting the default public key from remote server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. I then tried using the custom private key and it was prompting me for the passphrase. I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: What is the output of `ssh-add -l` on the client?

Comment: ```3072 SHA256:RPQ9p7SWFJGIWAmev3s9oFvGnXdSsaXrD1lD6ouM2DM student@workstation.example.com (RSA)```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Did you mean `ssh-add -L`? It's showing the public key that's under the `~/.ssh` directory.

Comment: In my tests both commands show the path. I don't know `ssh-add` well enough to tell when or why one of them may show differently, sorry. Anyway, it looks like the existence of SSH agent is a good lead.